# Why does Numpy matrix ignore demicals when assigned?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to assign decimal values into a NumPy matrix as shown below but when I do...

```
matrix = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
rn[1,] = [13.735,34.2,3]
```

It seems to ignore the decimal and just assigns the integer values into the matrix?

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
      [13, 34,  3]])
```

I couldn't find the reason why so far after some research

Comment: The desired data-type for the array. If not given, then the type will be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation, the desired data-type for the array. If not given, then the type will be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence. So since you did not specify the type when creating the array it inferred it to be an integer and not a float as all the values in the array are integers.

```
In [31]: import numpy as np

In [32]: matrix = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0]], dtype=np.float32)

In [33]: matrix
Out[33]: 
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)

In [34]: matrix[1,] = [13.735,34.2,3]

In [35]: matrix
Out[35]: 
array([[ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ],
       [13.735, 34.2  ,  3.   ]], dtype=float32)
```